# Reload vue2-bootstrap-table data using Ajax

Tags: ajax, vuejs2

Using `vue2-bootstrap-table` component, I want to force the component to call the `url` and refresh the data programmatically.

This is the component usage:

```
    <vue-bootstrap-table ref="table"
     :columns="columns"
     :ajax="tableAjax"
     :sortable="true"
     :paginated="true"
     :multi-column-sortable=true
     :show-filter="true"
>
</vue-bootstrap-table>
```

Now in a method I change the `url` as follows:

```
      this.tableAjax.url = NEW_URL
```

My question is how tell the `vue2-bootstrap-table` to reload the data using this new url

Comment: Hello, please ensure that when you ask questions you are providing us with a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. You can review these requirements here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Christopher OK. thanks. The text was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing all methods listed by Chrome browser console, I found that the `processFilter()` method will do that:

```
this.$refs['table'].processFilter()
```